# how to extract data(string) using php using regex?

Tags: php, regex

i have tried to extract

```
$str = "Instant Oatmeal - Corn Flavour 175g (35g x 5)";
preg_match('/(?P<name>.*) (?P<total_weight>\d+)(?P<total_weight_unit>.*) \((?P<unitWeight>\d+)(?P<unitWeight_unit>.*) x (?P<portion_no>\d+)\)/', $str, $m);
```

it is correct:

```
Instant Oatmeal - Corn Flavour 175g (35g x 5)
name : Instant Oatmeal - Corn Flavour
total_weight : 175 g
#portion : 5
unit weight : 35 g
```

However, if i want to extract

```
$str = "Cholcolate Sandwich Cookies (Tray) 264.6g (29.4g x 9)";
```

it is incorrect:

```
Cholcolate Sandwich Cookies (Tray) 264.6g (29.4g x 9)
name : Cholcolate Sandwich Cookies (Tray)
total_weight : 264 .6g
#portion : 9
unit weight : 29 .4g
```

How to solve this?

Comment: total weight should be:
    total_weight : 264.6g
however, it becomes
    total_weight : 264 .6g
the unit should be "g", but it is now ".6g"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
/(?P<name>.*) (?P<total_weight>\b[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(?P<total_weight_unit>.*) \((?P<unitWeight>\b[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(?P<unitWeight_unit>.*) x (?P<portion_no>\d+)\)/
```

Your problem is that you are not taking into account floating point numbers. I corrected this. Note that the portion is still an integer but I guess this is logical :)

Answer (score 3):

### Use free-spacing mode for non-trivial regexes!

When dealing with non-trivial regexes like this one, you can dramatically improve readability (and maintainability) by writing them in free-spacing format with lots of comments (and indentation for any nested parentheses). Here is your original regex in free spacing format with comments:

```php
$re_orig = '/# Original regex with added comments.
    (?P<name>.*)               # $name:
    [ ]                        # Space separates name from weight.
    (?P<total_weight>\d+)      # $total_weight:
    (?P<total_weight_unit>.*)  # $total_weight_unit:
    [ ]                        # Space separates totalunits from .
    \(                         # Literal parens enclosing portions data.
    (?P<unitWeight>\d+)        # $unitWeight:
    (?P<unitWeight_unit>.*)    # $unitWeight_unit:
    [ ]x[ ]                    # "space-X-space" separates portions data.
    (?P<portion_no>\d+)        # $portion_no:
    \)                         # Literal parens enclosing portions data.
    /x';
```

Here is an improved version:

```php
$re_improved = '/# Match Name, total weight, units and portions data.
    ^                       # Anchor to start of string.
    (?P<name>.*?)           # $name:
    [ ]+                    # Space(s) separate name from weight.
    (?P<total_weight>       # $total_weight:
      \d+                   # Required integer portion.
      (?:\.\d*)?            # Optional fractional portion.
    )
    (?P<total_weight_unit>  # $total_weight_unit:
      .+?                   # Units consist of any chars.
    )
    [ ]+                    # Space(s) separate total from portions.
    \(                      # Literal parens enclosing portions data.
    (?P<unitWeight>         # $unitWeight:
      \d+                   # Required integer portion.
      (?:\.\d*)?            # Optional fractional portion.
    )
    (?P<unitWeight_unit>    # $unitWeight_unit:
      .+?                   # Units consist of any chars.
    )
    [ ]+x[ ]+               # "space-X-space" separates portions data.
    (?P<portion_no>         # $portion_no:
      \d+                   # Required integer portion.
      (?:\.\d*)?            # Optional fractional portion.
    )
    \)                      # Literal parens enclosing portions data.
    $                       # Anchor to end of string.
    /xi';
```

Notes:

- The expressions for all the numerical quantities has been improved to allow an optional fractional portion.
- Added start and end of string anchors.
- Added `i` ignorecase modifier in case the `X` in the portions data is uppercase.

I'm not sure how you are applying this regex, but this improved regex should solve your immediate problem.

**Edit: 2011-10-09 11:17 MDT** Changed expression for units to be more lax to allow for cases pointed out by Ilmari Karonen.

Comment: `\w+` might not be enough for generic unit parsing, if there are any micrograms (`μg`), Ohms (`Ω`), Angstroms (`Å`), degrees (`°`) or feet and inches (`'` / `"`) involved. But I suppose none of those are very likely to appear in cooking recipes.  However, fluid ounces (`fl. oz`) might be a problem.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen - very good point. Have updated answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ridgerunner -thx very much, can you explain "(?:\.\d*)?" and "/xi" to me? I don't know what they mean..thx

Comment: `(?:\.\d*)?` means: _"Optionally match one literal dot followed by zero or more digits."_ I recommend spending some time learning the basic syntax. A good place to start is with the tutorials at: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). But if you really want to _"know"_ regex (in the Neo: _"I know kung-fu!"_ sense), I _highly_ recommend: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!"). This was the most useful book I have ever read.

Comment: Regarding: `/xi`, the `/` is the closing regex delimiter and the `x` and `i` are modifiers that tell the regex-engine to 1.) use free-spacing mode (`x`), and 2.) ignore case (`i`). See: [PHP PCRE Pattern Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).